# How to Left Join a table with an optional clause

Tags: mysql

I have this query where I want to find each ordered products with it's location

```
SELECT op.orders_id, op.products_id, op.products_quantity, op.products_name, psl.shelf_code
          FROM orders_products AS op
     LEFT JOIN orders_products_attributes AS opa
            ON op.orders_products_id = opa.orders_products_id
     LEFT JOIN products_stock_location AS psl
            ON op.products_id = psl.products_id
           AND opa.products_options_values_id = psl.option_id
         WHERE op.orders_id IN ('" . implode("', '", $oIDs) . "')
```

the thing is sometimes products don't have attributes so they don't have entries in orders_products_attributes, in this case my first Left join return nothing which is not an issue, but my AND clause make the second join return nothing.

Is there any way to make the and clause optional if not relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
and (opa.products_options_values_id is null
     or opa.products_options_values_id = psl.option_id)
```

Comment: of course that was easy, I was looking for some voodooish thing, must be the new year ;). thanks a lot.